# Unable to install elastic beanstalk cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following the instructions to install the eb cli:
https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup
However, upon running ./bundled_scripts, I'm getting this error:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/96/df02xppj77g7dx698gtmwmrw0000gn/T/python-build.20210326201347.50053
Results logged to /var/folders/96/df02xppj77g7dx698gtmwmrw0000gn/T/python-build.20210326201347.50053.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for python3.7... python3.7
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/96/df02xppj77g7dx698gtmwmrw0000gn/T/python-build.20210326201347.50053/Python-3.7.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
   Exiting due to failure
```

Of course I do have a c compiler since gcc --version shows:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you really need to build it? Can't install it using brew as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-osx.html)?

Comment: brew install gives me this error: Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-@react-native-community-cli-tools-5.0.1-alpha.0-e88c3ff6a2f33a39b6943323c29315372ebf0c57-integrity/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/.DS_Store

Comment: Maybe have to run it as a root

Comment: Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.

Comment: @lampbottle you dont need to use `sudo` with `brew install`. I just did `brew install` and it worked. While installing with brew it pulled these dependencies `Installing dependencies for aws-elasticbeanstalk: gdbm, openssl@1.1, sqlite and python@3.9` and now I have installed version `EB CLI 3.19.4 (Python 3.9.2)`. It is possible that some trouble with xcode . Can you try this `xcode-select --install`  and post that  if it still complains you can try updating the path `xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develope`. Between this error is pretty common.

Comment: even though it gave the error, turns out that eb was installed.